# Converting an overleaf text into Latex

Tags: errors, overleaf, document-classes, documentclass-writing, compilation-error

I have written a paper in Overleaf. I can't convert it into a LaTeX file. Is there any special way to do that.

For example the document class is `\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}` but in LaTeX it has not been defined and I will face an error. This template was from the journal templates.

Is there anyone help me fix the errors?
Thanks

Comment: Erh, how are you writing in overleaf and not using LaTeX, that is what overleaf does: use LaTeX. Perhaps you should explain your problem in greater detail. What exactly are you trying to do? at kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Do you mean this documentclass or style? http://tug.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/svlatex/

Comment: Sounds like you might be missing the `svmult` document class, which I cannot seem to find online anywhere... If you know where to get this file (likely `svmult.cls`), the easiest solution would be to place this file in same folder as your .tex file. *edit: is [this](https://github.com/openeventdata/Computational-Approaches/blob/master/svmult.cls) it?*

Comment: Overleaf is just a website with a standard texlive insallation, there is no "overleaf format" Your file is latex, you could get the svmult.cls file from your overleaf project, or download it from springer

Comment: @MS-SPO not that one (which is for latex2.09) Springer have a latex2e class